# Vagrant OpenBSD Box not starting up through Libvirt Provider

Tags: qemu, kvm, openbsd, libvirt, vagrant

So I have created a OpenBSD 7.3 VM in libvirt with the following shell command.

```
virt-install --name openbsd7.3 --os-variant openbsd7.0  \
--virt-type kvm --vcpus 1,maxvcpus=2 --memory 256,maxmemory=512 \
--disk /home/dev/Downloads/ISOs/install73.img,boot.order=1,format=raw  \
--disk /home/dev/Dev/VMs/openbsd7.3/openbsd73.img,boot.order=2,size=10 \
--cpu host-passthrough --boot uefi --import;
```

Then I completed the installation, removed the installer disk while VM was up.

```
virsh detach-disk --domain openbsd7.3 ~/Downloads/ISOs/install73.img \
--persistent --config --live
```

Then I setup sudo and vagrant user, insecure public key on the VM.

After completing the steps, I generated a `openbsd73.box` file from `openbsd73.img` with the [create_box.sh](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/blob/main/tools/create_box.sh) script from vagrant-libvirt github repo.

And then I added the .box to vagrant with

```
vagrant box add openbsd73.box --name openbsd73
```

After it was successfully added to Vagrant, I created a Vagrantfile to test it with

```
vagrant init openbsd73 && vagrant up --provider=libvirt
```

Although I get the following Error and the vagrant box doesn't start up

```
==> default: Starting domain.
==> default: Domain launching with graphics connection settings...
==> default:  -- Graphics Port:      5900
==> default:  -- Graphics IP:        127.0.0.1
==> default:  -- Graphics Password:  Not defined
==> default:  -- Graphics Websocket: 5700
==> default: Waiting for domain to get an IP address...
```

When I manually run `sudo virt-viewer <domain_name>` I get

```
Booting from hard Disk...
No active partition
```

**NOTE:** The box is available when I run `sudo virsh list --all` and the vagrant-libvirt virtual network is also active when I run `sudo virsh net-list --all` and it worked when I tried setting up a Alpine Linux box with Vagrant.